# efficient way of substracting along specific dimension in numpy array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a NumPy array `a` of sizes (1000,100,2).

I want to subtract only values from the last dimension iterating along the firsts.
In other words:

`a[i+1,j,[x1,y1]]-a[i,j,[x0,y0]]`

to obtain an array `b` of size (999,100,2)
with the last dimension that contains:

`[x1-x0, y1-y0] , etc...`

I know how to do that with a `for` loop, I'm looking for a more efficient "numpyzed" version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want `np.diff`

```
a = np.random.rand(1000, 100, 2)
b = np.diff(a, axis = 0)
b.shape
Out[]: (999, 100, 2)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but does it return the difference only on each element from the last dimension?